# How to avoid output into scrollable frames in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Suddenly, output for statements started to appear inside scrollable frames.

I was playing with only one parameter

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 1000
```

but after experiments, I commented this line out and restarted the kernel.

Nevertheless, one of my outputs appears inside frame.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Does resetting this to default by `pd.reset_option("display.max_rows")` help?

Comment: How can this affect if I restarted kernel?

Comment: No it didn't help.

Comment: `pd.options.displays.max_rows` just controls when `pandas` truncates output with a `...`. Scrollable frames are a part of Jupyter when the output for a given cell is long.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To disable auto-scrolling, execute this javascript in a notebook cell before other cells are executed:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}
```

There is also a jupyter notebook extension, [autoscroll](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/autoscroll), you can use for a nicer UI.

Comment: Is there a way to ENABLE auto-scrolling again after disabling using this javascript?

Comment: @Jianyu to ENABLE, you could just change `return false` to `return true`

Comment: Running this returns. "Javascript Error: IPython is not defined"

Answer (score 63):

You can just use mouse to click on the outside of the output Frame to toggle between scrolling, it worked for me.
More precisely, you have to click the square to the left of your output (see image).
[image: Where to click exactly]

Single click will toggle scroll mode, double click will hide output completely.

Comment: This also worked for me. Its not obvious. Clicking on the out sidebar toggles the scrollbar for that frame.

Comment: This is a very smart solution! You don't need to change any settings of Notebook!

Comment: Worked for me too.  All the time I've been using Jupyter Notebooks, and I didn't know this.  Very nice.

Comment: Does not work for me. clicking outside of the output frame has no effect. Does literally nothing.

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled across the same problem, a scrollbar appeared for outputs out of nowhere.

Just go to- Cell > All Outputs > Toggle Scrolling (On the Menu Bar) and outputs will go back to no scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by metadata in the jupyter `.ipynb` file. In my case the cell content looks like

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
    "scrolled": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "plot_timecourse(time, v_soma)"
   ]
  },
```

By just removing the scroll part, i.e. by removing the metadata:

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {}
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "plot_timecourse(time, v_soma)"
   ]
  },
```

fixed the issue of the weird scroll box.