# Why does Jupyter sometimes put plots in scrollable frames?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Below is a screenshot, in which I create two figures containing 4 plots, with near-identical code. Notably, plots both are the same size, and they are generated by the same line of code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2,figsize=(12, 10))
```

The first is displayed with no sliders, the second is displayed in a frame with sliders.

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid output into scrollable frames in jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641205/how-to-avoid-output-into-scrollable-frames-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thanks - that goes some way to answer the secondary question, but not the primary one (why does this happen?).

Comment: The reason it's so is because jupyter by default limits its output, e.g. consider a scenario, where the error message is too long. This is more of a feature.

Comment: But i am creating two figures the same size, why is it doing it for one and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But i am creating two figures the same size, why is it doing it for
> one and not the other?

It must be because you have clicked the rectangle box on the left of the output
[image]